# Why we need to use xmlns:android in xml design?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hey can you please explain me why we need to set

> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

in the xml layouts?

Answer (score 1):

This declares a namespace in xml.

This guarantees that the naming is unique, for example `android:id` or `android:layout_width` are `id` or `layout_width`, but in the namespace `android`, so `id` e.g. can be declared again in another namespace.

It is quite similar with a C# namespace or a java package.

the URI of the namespace is not a valid uri. It is just an unique identifier.